# To copy large files to remote server in node js

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to copy .war file(49,968 KB) to remote server using scp2 npm module.
But unable to copy. All other text files are copied, except the large files.
How will i proceed with this???

Comment: Did you try using `request` and pipe the response binary to an readable stream and save it?

Comment: Thank you for your reply Felix. Using scp2 npm, now i'm able to copy war file. But the nodejs doesnt wait till the copy completes.

Comment: client.scp('./Temporary_software_files/'+software_name+'/', {
    host: 'ip',
    username: 'centos',
    privateKey: String(require("fs").readFileSync('./pemfile.pem')),
    path: '/home/centos/Software_with_files/'+software_name
}, function(err,response) {
 if(err){
  console.log(err)
 }
 else{
  
  return callback(response.end())}
})

Comment: i have used the above code to copy.